# VBA Script running perfect in Debug mode - not pasting values without Debug mode

Tags: excel, vba

Dear Coding community,

I have written a little VBA Script to paste in some value from a user form into a table. Everything works as intended so far, until i leave the debug mode. Whenever i try to use the userform without the debug mode, none of the values will be copied to the table. Maybe its just a setting or a stupid mistake that i dont see at the moment. Thanks in advance for helping and have a great day everyone! Sorry for the variables being in german, i do this for a colleague so its easier for him to understand what i did...

This is the code:

```
Private Sub Bereich_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Beschlussdatum_Label_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Betreuer_Label_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Dienstleister_Textbox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Land_Label_Click()

End Sub


Private Sub Projekteinheit_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Projekt_ID_Combobox.List = Worksheets("Projektübersicht").Range("B4:B30").Value

End Sub

Private Sub Projektname_Change()
    
End Sub

Private Sub Projekt_ID_Combobox_Change()
    Projektname.Text = Application.VLookup(Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value, Worksheets("Projektübersicht").Range("B4:C40"), 2, False)
    Projekteinheit.Text = Application.VLookup(Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value, Worksheets("Projektübersicht").Range("B4:D40"), 3, False)
    Bereich.Text = Application.VLookup(Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value, Worksheets("Projektübersicht").Range("B4:E30"), 4, False)
End Sub

Private Sub Hinzufügen_CommandButton_Click()

Projekteingabe:

Dim ZeileFrei As Long
   
With Worksheets("Rechnungen")

Freie_Zeile = WorksheetFunction.Match("", Sheets("Rechnungen").Columns("C"), -1)

If Len(Trim(Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Projekt-ID darf nicht leer sein!")
    Unload Rechnung_hinzufügen
    Load Rechnung_hinzufügen
    Rechnung_hinzufügen.Show
End If

If Not Len(Trim(Umsatzssteuer_Textbox.Value)) = 0 Then
    Me.Umsatzssteuer_Textbox.Value = Format(Me.Umsatzssteuer_Textbox.Value / 100, "0.00%")
End If


Cells(Freie_Zeile, 2).Value = Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 6).Value = Dienstleister_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 7).Value = Land_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 8).Value = Leistungsdatum_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 9).Value = Rechnungsdatum_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 10).Value = Leistungsbeschreibung_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 11).Value = Betrag_Netto_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 12).Value = Umsatzssteuer_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 14).Value = Pruefung_Textbox.Value
Cells(Freie_Zeile, 15).Value = Rahmenvertrag_Textbox.Value

End With


MsgBox ("Die Rechnung wurde erfolgreich der Datenbank hinzugefügt.")
    If MsgBox("Willst du eine weitere Rechnung anlegen?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Unload Rechnung_hinzufügen
        Load Rechnung_hinzufügen
        Rechnung_hinzufügen.Show
    Else
        Unload Rechnung_hinzufügen
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Tried to delete all redundand code, broke it down to the core - nothing helped.

Comment: If you want to work with the worksheet "Rechnungen" (that you specify in the `With`-Clause, you need to put a dot in front of `Cells` (or any other property or method of the worksheet), else VBA will assume the active sheet and not the sheet of the `With`-clause: `.Cells(Freie_Zeile, 2).Value = Projekt_ID_Combobox.Value`